# json object to file in D3 V4,V5

Tags: json, csv, d3.js

I'm able to read a .csv file with d3.csv, stratify it and try to save the object to a file to generate a .json file for D3 graphs. Basically I'm doing a simple converter csv to json.

I'm using [D3 V5](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/download/v5.9.1/d3.zip) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) libraries only. Code runs fine until I arrive to JSON.stringify call that crashes. How can I safely save the root object generated in a .json file ?

.csv format file is also simple, first row is header describing row format: id, parentId, size

Code I'm using is simple:

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    var filecsv  = "data/Who.csv", 
        filejson = "data/Who.json"; 

    const partition = data => {
        const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
                .sum(d => d.data.size)
                .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
        return d3.partition()
                .size([2 * Math.PI, root.height + 1])
                (root);
    };

   d3.csv(filecsv).then(function(vCsvData) {
        var data = d3.stratify()(vCsvData);
        var root = partition(data);
        var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}); // crash here
        saveAs(blob, filejson);


    })
    .catch(function(error){
         console.log("Something wrong reading data from csv file...");
    });


}());
```

Comment: Is your error something like `TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures`? This would happen if you try to stringify the `root`... however, in your code, you're stringifying `data` instead.

Comment: Problem is that no error appears, simply the JSON.stringify does not return any valid object... Debugger also does not allow to check code in this function.

Comment: So, show us what it returns.